# Sequelize connecting to fail over write replica

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, failover, automatic-failover

I am using Sequelize 4.38.0. After reading the docs, I have setup a master write database with 2 read replicas. I am trying to add a fail over for the master write database for high availability. Does sequelize support this? Within the config options, in 'replications' you can pass an array of hosts to read, but not to write =\

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud SQL, the failover replica automatically replicates from the master and remains read only until a failover is needed. After a failover, the failover replica becomes the master and starts accepting writes. From the application's point of you, it's connecting to the same IP address.

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to know how I can test this? like can i somehow turn off the master write without the failover turning off? i tried stopping it, but then the failover stops too.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: What about local (not cloud) PostgreSQL clusters? After standby promotion, the application will try to write on an offline node which is configured in the write object and has the new primary node (able to write) on read object.